# Laravel login - Fail condition isn't working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm creating a login api in Laravel.

I have a login method

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(auth()->user());
        }

        return Response::json(['message' => 'Failed to authenticate'], 401);
    }
```

If the login fails it doesn't reach the 401 error. Any reason why?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson 5.8

Comment: You should show us what are you getting instead of 401 error, and how are you getting it

Comment: Did you import the `Response` facade? After a successful attempt, you use the `response()` helper instead.

Comment: use **try ... catch** for catch error if anything missing/wrong in your code

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(auth()->user());
    }
    else {
       return Response::json(['message' => 'Failed to authenticate'], 401);
    }
}
```

I would also `dd()` your `auth()` and make sure things are being pass as intended. Are you passing your CSRF token?

Also do you have your `Response` loaded using Use ../../Response; at the top of the controller?

Answer (score 0):

As @kray said, use dd() or echo"";print_r($credentials) to see if data is passed correctly. If not , then may be you haven't include {{ csrf_field() }} in your form.